# Function name shadowed by that function's parameter name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reflection, syntax

> Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of
> arguments.callee() in strict mode. Avoid using arguments.callee() by
> either giving function expressions a name or use a function
> declaration where a function must call itself.
> [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)]

How does one **reference the `o` function within itself** in the following situation?

```
function o(o) { o(); }
o('not a function'); // TypeError: o is not a function
```

EDIT:

**Why not rename the parameter/function?**

1. I am debugging thousands of files of obfuscated JavaScript code.
2. My own personal opinion is that this problem should be avoidable via reflection alone, not refactoring.

EDIT:

In the above situation, I am looking for either a way to reference the function within itself or, alternatively, **an explanation or a reference to a credible source as to why the parameter name shadows the function name**.

Comment: What's stopping you from renaming the parameter?

Comment: Yeah, why not rename the parameter? Your other alternative is to create a separate name for the same function and use that. Or something like a Y combinator. But seems like a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Fair question. Answered in edit.

Comment: "*My own personal opinion is that this problem should be avoidable via reflection alone, not refactoring.*" That's just like your opinion, man... It's not how the language works.

Comment: @VLAZ I prefixed the statement like that precisely to avoid such clashes. However, while this is, as stated by you and me, my own opinion, what you stated ("It's not how the language works.") is also your opinion, until proven otherwise. Hence my request for a reference to the standard. If you have one, please share it and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Naming a parameter a name that another declared variable has makes it the value in the function. It ignores the other declaration(s) and uses the one in the parameters. The best thing to do is rename it, but if it is in the global scope, you can access it with `window` (HTML documents only). Just type `window.functionName()` and it will reference correctly. This only works if it was defined in the global scope with the `var` keyword!

```js
//global scope
var a = 1
function b(a) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(window.a)
}
b(2) //2 and then 1
function o(o) {
  console.log(++a)
  if(a < 5) window.o() //calls o() from global scope
}
o()
```

Comment: Yes, the global scope did work for some places where I use this, but not all. The first two sentences make sense, but are they defined in the standard somehow? Separately, in my own opinion, this situation should be avoidable.

Comment: I think declaring a variable twice should be avoided

Comment: Agreed. However, it does not generate an error, so it is possible. For me, it goes down to the standard on why it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter o of o function is not a string. It should be a reference to any function or function name.

```
function a() { console.log('a function'); }
function o(o) { console.log('o function'); o(); }
o(a); 
// o function
// a function
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that's the point - I want to reference the function ```o``` itself, not the parameter, despite the same name for both.

Answer (score 0):

Used [shift-refactor](https://github.com/jsoverson/shift-refactor) to implement the obvious (`rename`) solution, as I did not find another one:

```
$source('FunctionDeclaration,FunctionExpression').forEach(fd => {
  if(fd.name)
  {
    for (let param of fd.params.items) {
      if (param.name === fd.name.name) {
        $source(param).rename('randomParameterName');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```